# Jquery ajax call result undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to parse JSON result retrieved from asp.net web method.

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string readCheckOutResult()
        {
            string uKey = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            string customerNo = HttpContext.Current.Session["customerNo"].ToString();
            Core core = new Core();
            DataTable dt = core.checkoutCustomerCart(customerNo, uKey); //dt = checked out product

            string JSONResult = DataTableToJSON.DataTableToJsonObj(dt);

            return JSONResult;
        }
```

Json Result received is somethink like below.

```
[{"CustomerNo":"33157880","ProductNo":"ALDC125DC-DIXON","CustomerProductNo":"","ProductDescription":"32MM AL D/CAST CAM TYPE DC  DIX     ",
"UOM":"  ","Price":"11.93200","Qty":"1","SubTotal":"11.93200","uKey":"201511131242","ModifyDate":"13/11/2015 12:42:25 PM","ID":"190"}]


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkout.aspx/readCheckOutResult",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(codes) {
        alert(codes.length);
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(codes.d);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            alert(data.d[i].CustomerNo);

        }

        alert(concatstring);

    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Failed to Retrieve Data.");
    }
});
```

I'm receiving the error codes.length is undefined. I also tried codes.d.length but no luck

Comment: why are you using async false?

Answer (score 2):

If you have specified the `dataType to json` no need to parse again

```
success: function(codes) {
    alert(codes.length);
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(codes.d);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
        alert(data.d[i].CustomerNo);

    }

    alert(concatstring);

}
```

should be

```
success: function(codes) {
    alert(codes.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        alert(codes[i].CustomerNo);

    }

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yv7p205/)